# Grails cache-ehache is not working properly

Tags: grails, ehcache

With the Grails ehcache plugin I'm trying to cache a response and occasionally refresh that response.

This is what I have in my Config.groovy,

```
cache {
    name 'userprojects'
    eternal false
    timeToIdleSeconds 60
    timeToLiveSeconds 60
    memoryStoreEvictionPolicy 'LRU'

}
```

And I am annotating the winners endpoint with @Cacheable('userprojects').

I am seeing the response get cached, but I am never see the cache expires. Anyone have any clue what might be going on here?

ehcache.EhcachePageFragmentCachingFilter Response ok. Adding to cache userprojects with key GET:/CompositeWeb/userMapping/userProjects?jiraInstance_id=1 and ttl 2147483647

Here the TTL is always set to Maximum value and not 60 as I configured.

Comment: Related [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12415029/grails-cache-ehcache-plugin-and-ttl-values) with additional details:

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same issue and I think I"ve found the solution.  I opened the following JIRA http://jira.grails.org/browse/GPCACHEEHCACHE-6 and will be submitting a pull request over the weekend.  I tested my changes locally and they work fine.

The problem was that the put() call is not using the TTL of the cache, but rather a default value.